# Ziggeo JavaScript API aspect ratio does not adapt to a recently uploaded video

Tags: javascript, video-processing, ziggeo-sdk

given

- aspect ratio settings has its default value or any specific value
- video upload is enabled
- video recording is enabled
- user uploads a file with aspect ratio that differs from initial value (640/480 is a default)

video plays after uploading in the same component but cropped. yet it is visible normally if the same video is rendered at the start of the component.

ziggeo-* settings like aspect ratio, width, height, videofitstrategy do have effect on the startup state, but after uploaded file is processed and it is (in principle) possible to detect correct aspect ratio the component fails to do so.

How to make the Ziggeo component to adapts its playback after uploading?

example:

Video file looks like this (portrait)

[image: video to be uploaded]

Upload video in the player (640/480 aspect ratio)

[image: video after uploading]

integration code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//assets-cdn.ziggeo.com/v2-stable/ziggeo.css" />
<script src="//assets-cdn.ziggeo.com/v2-stable/ziggeo.js"></script>
<script> 
var ziggeo_app = new ZiggeoApi.V2.Application(
{
  token: "token-here-inserted",
  auth: true
});
</script>

<ziggeorecorder
  id="myRecorder"
  ziggeo-timelimit="time-limit-here-specifiecd"
  ziggeo-perms="allowupload"
  ziggeo-filesizelimit="file-size-here-spedified">
</ziggeorecorder>
```